# NodeJs, Promises not waiting

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have this function that should make 300 requests for a web page (for benchmarking), however the Promise.all is not waiting for those requests to finish before outputting an empty array, any ideas?

```
function requestLoop(){

  var resultSet= [];

  // options.requests = 300
  // options.url = http://localhost/

  for(var c=1;c<=options.requests; c++){

    http.get(options.url, function(res){

    //  resultSet.push( { request: c, statusCode: res.statusCode});

      resultSet.push(new Promise(function(res){ return { request: c, statusCode: res.statusCode}; }));

    });

  }

  Promise.all(resultSet).then(function(){
    console.log(resultSet);
  });

  return;

}
```

Promise is bluebird and http is the normal http package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You are creating promises in callback.When  `Promise.all(resultSet)` is executed non of promises was created.

Comment: I would disagree, I am not using AJAX and that question only refers to a single request, I am attempting to make multiple and bring the results together.

Comment: `http.get` returns promise too.. You should be pushing that in array!

Comment: Is there an example showing this at all?

Comment: It doesn't matter what is the source of async in your code: ajax or http.get or whatever. The reason is the same.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko — I do not think OP is returning the response.. He is using Promise but implementation is wrong....

Comment: @Rayon No difference between returning or pushing to external array.

Comment: And BTW no difference if you are returning a Promise from callback or anything else. This is still returning from asynchronous call. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Promise is being pushed in array in callback. Hence By the time `Promise.all` invokes, array is empty(`[]`)

Push `new Promise` in array within loop itself, not in `callback`

```js
function requestLoop() {
  var resultSet = [];
  for (var c = 1; c <= options.requests; c++) {
    (function(c) {
      resultSet.push(new Promise(function(resolve) {
        http.get(options.url, function(res) {
          resolve({
            request: c,
            statusCode: res.statusCode
          });
        });
      }));
    })(c);
  }
  Promise.all(resultSet).then(function() {
    console.log(resultSet);
  });
}
```